Tests fail on GitHub Actions but not on my local environment
I have the following workflow:
name: FastAPI endpoint  
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: "3.10"
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install pytest pylint 
        make install 
    - name: Lint with Pylint
      run: |
        pylint --disable=R,C *.py || true 
    - name: Create .env file 
      run: |
        touch .env 
        echo OPENAI_API_KEY=${{ secrets.OPENAI_API_KEY }} >> .env
        echo GEMINI_API_KEY=${{ secrets.GEMINI_API_KEY }} >> .env 
        echo HF_TOKEN=${{ secrets.HF_TOKEN }} >> .env 
        echo FILE_ID=${{ secrets.FILE_ID }} >> .env 
        cat .env
    - name: Intialize the Server 
      run: |
        fastapi run main.py & sleep 5
    - name: Checking the status of the output
      run: |
        python test.py 
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pytest test.py 

The pytest test.py keeps failing on GitHub Actions. These are the tests:
def test_data_loader() -> None: 
    if not os.listdir(PDF_BASE_PATH): return 
    for pdf_filename in os.listdir(PDF_BASE_PATH): 
        with open(os.path.join(PDF_BASE_PATH, pdf_filename), "rb") as f: 
            byte_content = f.read() # reading the content in bytes 

        # test if the files are working 
        files = {
            "pdf_file": (pdf_filename, byte_content, "application/pdf"), 
        }

        response = requests.post(API_URL + "/data_loader", files=files)
        print(response.content)
        assert isinstance(response.json(), list)
    
    files = {
        "pdf_file": (pdf_filename, b'', "image/jpeg")
    }


    # test if the http error occurs correctly 
    response = requests.post(API_URL + "/data_loader", files=files, timeout=300 )
    assert response.status_code == 400  
   
def test_data_classifer() -> None: 
    headers: Dict[str, str] = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    response = requests.post(
        API_URL + "/data_classifier", 
        json=data_classifier_json, 
        headers=headers, 
        timeout=300, 
    )

    print(response.content)

    output_json: List[Dict] = response.json()

    for json_result in output_json: 
        assert list(json_result.keys()) == [
            "root_concept", 
            "major_domains", 
            "sub_domains", 
            "concepts", 
            "Attributes and connections", 
            "formal_representations", 
            "heading_identifier", 
            "heading_text", 
            "sub_heading_text", 
            "text_type", 
            "paragraph_number", 
            "text", 
        ]

def test_generate() -> None: 
    json: Dict[str, str|List[str]] = {
        "context": book_text, 
        "topics": topics
    }

    headers: Dict[str, str] = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    response = requests.post(
        API_URL + "/generate", 
        json=json, 
        headers=headers, 
    )

    print(response.content)     
    assert isinstance(response.json()["output"], str)  

The tests work locally perfectly, however running them on GitHub Actions gives me the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
b'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.15/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 165, in __call__\n    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)\n  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.15/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 62, in __call__\n    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)\n  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.15/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 62, in wrapped_app\n    raise exc\n  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.15/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 51, in wrapped_app\n    await app(scope, receive, sender)\n  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.15/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 715, in __call__\n    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)\n  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.15/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 735, in app\n    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)\n  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.15/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 288, in handle\n    await self.app(scope, receive, send)\n  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.15/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 76, in app\n    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)\n  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.15/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 62, in wrapped_app\n    raise exc\n  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.15/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 51, in wrapped_app\n    await app(scope, receive, sender)\n  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.15/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 73, in app\n    response = await f(request)\n  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.15/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 301, in app\n    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(\n  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.15/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 212, in run_endpoint_function\n    return await dependant.call(**values)\n  File "/home/runner/work/project-astra/project-astra/main.py", line 100, in data_classifier\n    op: Dict[str, Dict|str|None|int|List[str]]|str = get_json(t_json, HF_TOKEN)\n  File "/home/runner/work/project-astra/project-astra/data_classifier/classification_pipeline.py", line 36, in get_json\n    extracted_json = response[0]["generated_text"].split("Extracted JSON:")[1].split("###")[0].strip()\nKeyError: 0\n'
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.15/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 974, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.15/x64/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.15/x64/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.15/x64/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

The error is coming when I try to decode the JSON.
I tried print statements and adding a new step to the workflow as you can see here in the YAML file:
 - name: Checking the status of the output
      run: |
        python test.py 

But that doesn't seem to help at all, as it does not print the JSON in any of the steps. The print statements don't show any output on GitHub Actions.
I suspect the error is because of OpenAI and Gemini API keys not being found, but I can't be sure because I have no idea how to debug this. I think it's not able to load the .env files but, like I said. I can't be sure.
I tried adding the environment to the YAML file:
name: FastAPI endpoint  
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Set up Python 3.11
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: "3.11"
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install pytest pylint 
        sudo apt install poppler-utils 
        make install 
    - name: Lint with Pylint
      run: |
        pylint --disable=R,C *.py || true 
    - name: Intialize the Server 
      run: |
        fastapi run main.py & sleep 5
      env: 
        OPENAI_API_KEY=${{ secrets.OPENAI_API_KEY }}
        GEMINI_API_KEY=${{ secrets.GEMINI_API_KEY }}
        HF_TOKEN=${{ secrets.HF_TOKEN }}
        FILE_ID=${{ secrets.FILE_ID }}

    - name: Checking the status of the output
      run: |
        python test.py 

      env: 
        OPENAI_API_KEY=${{ secrets.OPENAI_API_KEY }}
        GEMINI_API_KEY=${{ secrets.GEMINI_API_KEY }}
        HF_TOKEN=${{ secrets.HF_TOKEN }}
        FILE_ID=${{ secrets.FILE_ID }}
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pytest test.py 
      env: 
        OPENAI_API_KEY=${{ secrets.OPENAI_API_KEY }}
        GEMINI_API_KEY=${{ secrets.GEMINI_API_KEY }}
        HF_TOKEN=${{ secrets.HF_TOKEN }}
        FILE_ID=${{ secrets.FILE_ID }}

however I got the following error:
Error: The template is not valid. .github/workflows/python-app.yml (Line: 37, Col: 9): Unexpected value 'OPENAI_API_KEY= GEMINI_API_KEY= HF_TOKEN= FILE_ID='


Your second example fails because that's simply not how you set env vars for a step in GHA, or even write valid YAML.

try providing env variables as part of python script calling step -
- name: Checking the status of the output
      run: |
        python test.py
      env:
        OPENAI_API_KEY=${{ secrets.OPENAI_API_KEY }}
        GEMINI_API_KEY=${{ secrets.GEMINI_API_KEY }}
        HF_TOKEN=${{ secrets.HF_TOKEN }}
        FILE_ID=${{ secrets.FILE_ID }}


That gave me the following error:
Error: The template is not valid. .github/workflows/python-app.yml (Line: 37, Col: 9): Unexpected value 'OPENAI_API_KEY= GEMINI_API_KEY= HF_TOKEN= FILE_ID='


can you paste your yaml file, this error must be related indentation error in the config file I gues.

If you echo those variables, are they actually there? From the error it looks like the secrets are not set (or there might be some permission issue in github).
